# custom sparql filter Graphdb

Tags: graphdb

One of the things I would like to do is, implement my own SPARQL filter in GraphDB. GraphDB works with RDF4J so I was wondering whether such construction: http://docs.rdf4j.org/custom-sparql-functions/#_implementing_the_custom_function_as_a_java_class would be possible within GraphDB? I was looking around, but I cannot find where such JAR should be placed within GraphDB if possible?

First question is, is it possible to implement a own SPARQL Filter?

Comment: It works with any custom functions, just place your JAR somewhere in the classpath and don't forget to embed the SPI configuration in it (section 3 from the link you've posted)

Comment: @DamyanOgnyanov what classpath? The classpath of your project using RDF4J to query, or the classpath of GraphDB itself?

Comment: @medium The classpath is of the Graphdb server instance where your SPARQL query will be evaluated. The evaluation engine will find the code that is associated with the IRI of your function and call it. The discovery and registration of the function require that the SPI metadata (noted in the comment above) is present in your jar.

Comment: @DamyanOgnyanov I attempted to do this but still get the error: Unknown function 'http://example.org/custom-function/palindrome' . I placed my jar in /graphDBFree/runtime/lib, would this be the correct place?

Comment: @medium place the jar in `/graphDBFree/app/lib` not in `/graphDBFree/runtime/lib`

Comment: @DamyanOgnyanov thanks, I still get the error. Is there a way to debug this?

Comment: @medium indeed, it was not enough to only place the jar into `/graphDBFree/app/lib` folder. The embedded launcher uses an explicit classpath setting to list all the jars. 
In `app` folder there should be a file named `graphDB Free.cfg` which you need to edit and add your jar to the `app.classpath=' entry.

Answer (score 0):

Is this resolved?

The only other thing I see is the error is reported as 'example.org/custom-function/palindrome': shouldn't this have `http://` at the front?