# GraphDB load RDF4J custom SPARQL function in Docker image

Tags: graphdb

I'm having trouble loading my RDF4J custom SPARQL function in GraphDB.

I'm running GraphDB 10.2.0 using the Docker image at https://hub.docker.com/r/ontotext/graphdb.

I've followed https://rdf4j.org/documentation/tutorials/custom-sparql-functions/ and created a custom SPARQL function in RDF4J. I've added the SPI configuration as described in the documentation and packaged it up into a JAR file.

I'm running the GraphDB container with the following `docker-compose.yml` file.

```yaml
version: "3.8"

services:
  graphdb:
    image: ontotext/graphdb:10.2.0
    volumes:
      - graphdb-data:/opt/graphdb/home
      - ./build/libs/palindrome-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar:/opt/graphdb/dist/lib/plugins/example-plugin/palindrome-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
    ports:
      - 7200:7200
    environment:
      # Note: running GraphDB in DEBUG mode
      GDB_JAVA_OPTS: >-
        -Xmx4g
        -Xms2g
        -Dgraphdb.home=/opt/graphdb/home
        -Dgraphdb.workbench.importDirectory=/opt/graphdb/home/graphdb-import
        -Dgraphdb.workbench.cors.enable=true
        -Denable-context-index=true
        -Dentity-pool-implementation=transactional
        -Dhealth.max.query.time.seconds=600
        -Dgraphdb.append.request.id.headers=true
        -Dreuse.vars.in.subselects=true
        -Dgraphdb.logger.root.level=DEBUG
    networks:
      - graphdb
    profiles:
      - graphdb

volumes:
  graphdb-data:

networks:
  graphdb:
```

Once GraphDB has started up. I load some data.

```
@prefix rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#>.
@prefix ex: <http://example.org/> .

ex:a rdfs:label "step on no pets" .
ex:b rdfs:label "go on, try it" .
```

And I run the SPARQL query.

```
PREFIX rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#>
PREFIX cfn: <http://example.org/custom-function/>
SELECT ?x ?label
WHERE {
   ?x rdfs:label ?label .
   FILTER(cfn:palindrome(str(?label)))
}
```

However, running the query responds with the following error.

```
Error 500: error
Query evaluation error: Unknown function 'http://example.org/custom-function/palindrome' (HTTP status 500)
```

I've looked at existing Stackoverflow questions which seem to suggest RDF4J custom functions can work in GraphDB.

- [Implement custom RDF4J function for GraphDB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53711234/implement-custom-rdf4j-function-for-graphdb)
- [custom sparql filter Graphdb](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52337703/custom-sparql-filter-graphdb)

Please can someone guide me on how to load a custom SPARQL function written with RDF4J. Thanks in advance.